# Subclassing __dir__ on a Python module

Tags: python-3.x, super, python-class

Beginning in Python 3.7 it is possible to define `__dir__()` on a module.  But what if you want to take the "normal" output of `dir(module)` and add or remove from it?

For instance, I would like to do something like this:

```
def __dir__():
    dir_out = super().__dir__()[:]  # does not work
    dir_out.pop('Optional')  # get rid of the typing imports
    return dir_out
```

Obviously because a module is not a normal class, the `super()` call does not work.  But is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `globals()` command to get what normally would appear in dir:

```
def __dir__():
    dir_out = list(globals()) 
    dir_out.pop('Optional')  # get rid of the typing imports
    return dir_out
```

Comment: Figured this out just before posting the Q -- though it is a different question, an answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61984376/should-i-hide-imports-of-dependencies-in-a-python-module-from-the-dir-method helped)